# Sums of powers mod p

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, finite-fields

For prime $p > 7$ with $p-1=rs$, $r>1$, $s>1$, let $A=\{x^r|x \in \mathbb{Z}_p\}$ and $B = \{x^s|x \in \mathbb{Z}_p\}$. If $g$ is a primitive root mod $p$ then $A = \{0\} \cup \{g^{ir}|0 \leq i < s \}$ and $B = \{0\} \cup \{g^{js}|0 \leq j < r \}$.  Is it always true that $\mathbb{Z}_p \neq A + B$?

Comment: It doesn't follow directly from Hasse-Weil, so it's not obviously false. Do you have numerical evidence?

Comment: If you take $r=2$, then you're asking if, for any $p$, there are $n, n+1, n+2$ which are not quadratic residues. Is that true?

Comment: @Felipe:  Yes, so far it appears to hold numerically.  I just tried p = 113117 for fun.  p-1 = 4*28279. When r = 2, s= 2*28279 I get |A+B| = 98903.  If r = 4, s = 28279 then |A+B| = 86330. The gap between A+B and Z_p seems to grow larger and larger as p increases.  Moreover it also appears that for given p and different factorizations of p-1 = rs, as r and s get closer, |A+B| gets smaller, so the largest |A+B| seems to occur when r = 2, s = (p-1)/2. Maple is just too slow, I need to write a program to test larger cases and see a trend.

@Zack: Forgive my ignorance, how do you get that?

Comment: @Jose: let me try to answer for Zack. If $r=2$, then $A$ consists of $0$ and
all quadratic residues, and $B=\{-1,0,1\}$. So, $A+B=Z_p$ if and only if any
$n$ is at distance at most $1$ from a quadratic residue (or $0$), and $A+B\ne
Z_p$ if and only if there exists a run of three consecutive quadratic
non-residues.

Comment: If $r$ and $s$ are both large, then from $|A||B|=p+r+s$ it follows that the
total number of possible sums of the form $a+b$ with $a\in A$ and $b\in B$
only slightly exceeds $p$; and so, it suffices to have a very small amount of
overlapping for the statement to hold.


Comment: @Zack Wolske: If $r=2$, then we can prove that your statement is true for sufficiently large prime $p$. The proof makes use of Weil's bound.
Reference: On the Distribution of Quadratic Residues and Nonresidues Modulo a Prime Number, AMS,  Mathematics of Computation, Vol. 58, No. 197 (Jan., 1992), pp. 433-440

Comment: Yes, Seva, I agree.  How do we quantify the number of duplicate sums?

Comment: @i707107: if $r=2$, the statement is true by very elementary properties of the Legandre symbol - no need to use Weil's bound.

Comment: @Jose: consider the number of solutions of $a_1+b_1=a_2+b_2$. It suffices to show that it is just slightly larger than the trivial bound $|A||B|$, coming from counting the solutions with $a_1=a_2$ and $b_1=b_2$.

Comment: @Jose, @Felipe: The result is true for the first 2000 primes - up to $17419$.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks, it would be interesting to check if my other observation ( that for fixed p and different factorizations of p-1 = rs with 1 < r <= s then as r increases,  |A+B| decreases) holds as well.

Comment: @Jose For $p=13,$    $r,s=2,6$ gives $|A+B|=11$    while $r,s=3,4$ gives $|A+B|=12. $  That is the only exception I saw up to $293$. 

Comment: @Seva: I don't see that the statement follows from elementary properties of the Legendre symbol, I am very interested to see the proof, can you show me? 

Comment: The statement implies that if $p-1=q^2t$, then every element in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a sum of two $q$-th powers. Is it known?

Comment: @i707107: this is just to confirm that I will reply in essence later today or tomorrow. Stay tuned :-)

Comment: The condition $p>7$ can be removed.  Very important. :)

Comment: @Mark : How does a positive answer (the sum is never the whole thing) imply what you say ?

Comment: @BS: You are right. It is just a similar and simpler, question. I asked it separately, and it has been answered already, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/92825/sums-of-two-same-powers-modulo-p . The answer by Mark Lewko there may help with this question also. 

Answer (score 12):

This is a very partial answer, addressing the extreme cases $r=2$ and $r=s$ only.

For $r=s$ we have $A=B$ and $|A|=|B|=r+1$. Hence 
  $$ |A+B|\le \binom{r+1}2+(r+1)=\frac{p+3r+1}{2} < p, $$ 
implying $A+B\ne{\mathbb F_p}$.

This trivial argument extends onto the case where $r$ and $s$ have a sufficiently large greatest common divisor. Namely, writing $d=(r,s)$, we have $|A\cap B|=d+1$; it follows that at least $(d+1)^2-\binom{d+1}2=(d+1)(d+2)/2$ sums $a+b$ are wasted on double representations. Therefore 
  $$ |A+B|\le |A||B|-\frac{(d+1)(d+1)}2=p+r+s-\frac{(d+1)(d+2)}2; $$
as a result, if $(d+1)(d+2)>2(r+s)$, then $A+B\ne{\mathbb F}_p$.

For $r=2$ the problem reduces to showing that for any sufficiently large prime $p$, there is a run of three consecutive quadratic non-residues $\mod p$. This is easy to prove using Weil's bound, but can be done in an elementary way, as follows.
The following argument actually works for all $p\ge 11$. Suppose, for a
contradiction, that for any $z\in{\mathbb F}_p$, at least one of $z,z-1$, and
$z+1$ is a square. Then
  $$ \Big(\Big(\frac{z-1}p\Big)-1\Big)
     \Big(\Big(\frac{z}p\Big)-1\Big)
     \Big(\Big(\frac{z+1}p\Big)-1\Big) = 0 $$
for every $z\in{\mathbb F}_p$, except that if
$\Big(\frac{-1}p\Big)=\Big(\frac{-2}p\Big)=-1$, then for $z=-1$ this product
is equal to $-4$. Letting $\delta=1$ in this case and $\delta=0$ otherwise,
we thus have
  $$ \sum_{z\in\mathbb F_p}
     \Big(\Big(\frac{z-1}p\Big)-1\Big)
     \Big(\Big(\frac{z}p\Big)-1\Big)
     \Big(\Big(\frac{z+1}p\Big)-1\Big) = -4\delta. $$
Opening the parentheses and evaluating "quadratic sums" yields
  $$ \sum_{z\in{\mathbb F}_p} \Big(\frac{(z-1)z(z+1)}p\Big) = (p-3) - 4\delta. $$
This shows that for all $z\in{\mathbb F}_p\setminus\{-1,0,1\}$, writing for
brevity $f(z)=(z-1)z(z+1)$, we have $\Big(\frac{f(z)}p\Big)=1$, save for
exactly $2\delta$ exceptional values of $z$. Observing that $f(-z)=-f(z)$, we
conclude that $\Big(\frac{-1}p\Big)=1$; hence $\delta=0$, meaning that,
indeed, $\Big(\frac{f(z)}p\Big)=1$ for *all* $z\in{\mathbb
F}_p\setminus\{-1,0,1\}$, without any exceptions.

What we have shown so far is that $f(z)$ is a quadratic residue for each
$z\in{\mathbb F}_p\setminus\{-1,0,1\}$. Consequently, so is
$f(z+1)/f(z)=(z+2)/(z-1)=1+3/(z-1)$, an evident nonsense!

Comment: That's very clever. Thank you for the nice solution. Thinking about the use of Weil's bound, the reference paper by R. Peralta gives much stronger assertion: For large enough p, there exists any "R(quadratic residue)" "N(quadratic nonresidue" sequence of length $u\log_2 p$ where $u<1/2$. 

Comment: Sure. However, for sequences of length $3$ this can be done by elementary means.

Comment: Nice. Probably the most difficult case is when (r,s) = 1.

Comment: A similar argument should show that, for fixed $r$, the statement is true for all sufficiently large $p$ with $p \equiv 1 \mod r$.

Comment: @David Speyer: A similar argument will be involving character sums of polynomial of degree $r$. This argument for $r=2$ was easy because the other terms were character sums of quadratic polynomial(e.g. $n(n+1)$, $n(n-1)$, $n^2-1$). So, I don't think the similar argument is applicable in $r>2$ case. 

Answer (score 2):

For fixed $r>1$, use of Weil's bound will give the result. 
    We refer to Theorem 5.1 from chapter 2 of W.M.Schmidt, Equations over Finite Fields: An Elementary Approach.

**Theorem**
    Let $f_1,\cdots, f_n$ be polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_q$ and of degree $\leq m$. Put $\delta=\textrm{lcm}(d_1,\cdots,d_n)$, and $d=d_1d_2\cdots d_n$. Let X be a variable and let $\eta_1,\cdots,\eta_n$ be algebraic quantities with
    \begin{equation}
    \eta_1^{d_1}=f_1(X), \cdots, \eta_n^{d_n}=f_n(X).\
    \end{equation}
    Suppose
    \begin{equation}
    [\overline{\mathbb{F}}_q(X, \eta_1,\cdots,\eta_n):\overline{\mathbb{F}}_q(X)]=d.
    \end{equation}
    Then if $q>100\delta^3m^2n^2$, the number $N$ of solutions $(x,y_1,\cdots,y_n)\in\mathbb{F}_q^{n+1}$ of the equations $y_1^{d_1}=f_1(X),\cdots,y_n^{d_n}=f_n(X)$ satisfies
    \begin{equation}
    |N-q|<5mnd\delta^{5/2}q^{1/2}.
    \end{equation} 
    We will use this theorem to solve the problem for fixed $r>1$. We have $q=p$ prime number. Let $g$ be a primitive root modulo $p$. We put $n=r+1$, $m=1$, $d_1=\cdots=d_n=r$, $\delta=r$, $d=r^{r+1}$, $f_i(X)=g(X-g^{is})$ for $0\leq i \leq r-1$, and $f_r(X)=gX$. Then the condition is satisfied, and the number $N$ of solutions to the system $Y_i^r=f_i(X)$ ($0\leq i \leq r$) is 
    \begin{equation}
    |N-p|<5(r+1) r^{r+1+5/2}p^{1/2}.
    \end{equation}

We look for the number $N^{*}$ of solutions with no $Y_i$ being zero. 
Then we have
$$N^{*}\geq p-5(r+1) r^{r+1+5/2}p^{1/2}-(r+1)r^{r+1}.$$ 
This is in fact greater than zero for sufficiently large $p$. For any such solution $(X,Y_0,\cdots, Y_r)\in \mathbb{F}_p^{r+2}$, we obtain that
$$X\in \mathbb{Z}_p-(A+B).$$ 
This proves the result.

Comment: Very nice, it isn't obvious to see how to cast the problem into the form required by the theorem.

Comment: My bound for "Sufficiently large $p$" depends on $r$. So my solution does not completely settle your question. 